# SPDY on web browser control

Tags: windows, registry, internet-explorer-11, spdy

I am trying to enable SPDY on web browser control (Internet Explorer 11/WIN 8.1).
In Internet Explorer advanced settings and in the registry the EnableSPDY3_0 is set to 1.
But in my web browser control the SPDY is not working.
Are there other settings that I need to configure?

Answer (score 4):

How *specifically* are you attempting to detect SPDY?

I took a quick look with Fiddler and confirmed that SPDY is not used by the Web Browser control outside of IE itself. As this is a new and somewhat experimental feature, I'm not that surprised that the WebOC isn't using it yet.

If you rename your executable to `iexplore.exe` then you will find that SPDY *is* used. (**WARNING: This isn't recommended for many functionality and security reasons**.) That behavior indicates that they're using a FEATURE_CONTROL KEY to control whether SPDY is permitted; feature control keys work on a per-process basis.

I don't see a documented entry for this feature in the [official FEATURE_CONTROL list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Internet Explorer's documentation writer and networking PM have confirmed that this is deliberately not documented and suggest that a bug be filed at connect.microsoft.com if you'd like to see a change in policy on this.

Comment: well, according to wikipedia (with citations), its not IE only feature as it is first developed by Google and going towards standardization.
[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY)

Comment: No one said that it's an "IE only feature"-- IE was the *last* major browser to add support. If you read my response, you'll note that I said that "SPDY is not used by the Web Browser control outside of IE itself." **Web Browser control** is how Microsoft refers to the hosting of IE's components inside other applications.